# Build fails on secure browser 7 (Firefox 29)

Tags: c++, python-2.7, firefox

I came across this project https://bitbucket.org/sbacoss/securebrowser7_release and I was interested in trying to build this project.

So I followed the guide in the README.md file.

I am running Windows 8.1 and installed VS2010 Express Edition. I also have Windows Driver Kit for Windows 8.1 and I also have Windows SDK for 8.1.

Note:- I even have VS 2013 Express for Web and VS 2013 Express for Desktop also installed for other projects that I work on.

Now the problem is that even after following all the steps, the build fails in first few minutes.

Below is the content of my log:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

configure:1197: checking host system type
configure:1218: checking target system type
configure:1236: checking build system type
configure:1311: checking for mawk
configure:1311: checking for gawk
configure:1397: checking for python2.7
configure:1397: checking for python
configure:1507: checking Python environment is Mozilla virtualenv
configure:1728: checking for perl5
configure:1728: checking for perl
configure:3117: checking for gcc
configure:3230: checking whether the C compiler (cl  ) works
configure:3246: cl -o conftest    conftest.c  1>&5
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

cl : Command line warning D9035 : option 'o' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release
conftest.c
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 10.00.40219.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:conftest.exe 
/out:conftest.exe 
conftest.obj 
configure:3272: checking whether the C compiler (cl  ) is a cross-compiler
configure:3277: checking whether we are using GNU C
configure:3286: cl -E conftest.c
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

conftest.c
configure:3305: checking whether cl accepts -g
configure:3346: checking for c++
configure:3378: checking whether the C++ compiler (cl  ) works
configure:3394: cl -o conftest    conftest.C  1>&5
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

cl : Command line warning D9035 : option 'o' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release
conftest.C
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 10.00.40219.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:conftest.exe 
/out:conftest.exe 
conftest.obj 
configure:3420: checking whether the C++ compiler (cl  ) is a cross-compiler
configure:3425: checking whether we are using GNU C++
configure:3434: cl -E conftest.C
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

conftest.C
configure:3453: checking whether cl accepts -g
configure:3487: checking for ranlib
configure:3519: checking for ml
configure:3573: checking for ar
configure:3608: checking for ld
configure:3643: checking for strip
configure:3678: checking for windres
configure:3877: checking for midl
configure:3926: cl -c  -TC -nologo  conftest.c 1>&5
conftest.c
configure:3951: cl -c  -TP -nologo  conftest.C 1>&5
conftest.C
configure:4113: checking for std::_Throw
configure:4136: cl -c  -TP -nologo -D_HAS_EXCEPTIONS=0  conftest.C 1>&5
conftest.C
configure(4132) : error C2039: '_Throw' : is not a member of 'std'
configure(4132) : error C3861: '_Throw': identifier not found
configure: failed program was:
#line 4129 "configure"
#include "confdefs.h"
#include <exception>
int main() {
std::_Throw(std::exception()); return 0;
; return 0; }
configure:4219: checking for overridable _RAISE
configure:4246: cl -c  -TP -nologo -D_HAS_EXCEPTIONS=0  conftest.C 1>&5
conftest.C
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\\Include\exception(263) : error C3861: 'externallyDefinedFunction': identifier not found
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\\Include\exception(333) : error C3861: 'externallyDefinedFunction': identifier not found
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\\Include\exception(361) : error C3861: 'externallyDefinedFunction': identifier not found
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\\Include\typeinfo(171) : error C3861: 'externallyDefinedFunction': identifier not found
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\\Include\typeinfo(192) : error C3861: 'externallyDefinedFunction': identifier not found
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\\Include\stdexcept(39) : error C3861: 'externallyDefinedFunction': identifier not found
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\\Include\stdexcept(67) : error C3861: 'externallyDefinedFunction': identifier not found
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\\Include\stdexcept(95) : error C3861: 'externallyDefinedFunction': identifier not found
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\\Include\stdexcept(123) : error C3861: 'externallyDefinedFunction': identifier not found
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\\Include\stdexcept(151) : error C3861: 'externallyDefinedFunction': identifier not found
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\\Include\stdexcept(179) : error C3861: 'externallyDefinedFunction': identifier not found
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\\Include\stdexcept(207) : error C3861: 'externallyDefinedFunction': identifier not found
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\\Include\stdexcept(235) : error C3861: 'externallyDefinedFunction': identifier not found
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\\Include\stdexcept(263) : error C3861: 'externallyDefinedFunction': identifier not found
configure: failed program was:
#line 4235 "configure"
#include "confdefs.h"
#include <xstddef>
                                    #undef _RAISE
                                    #define _RAISE(x) externallyDefinedFunction((x).what())
                                    #include <vector>

int main() {
std::vector<int> v; return v.at(1);
; return 0; }
configure:4395: checking for winsdkver.h
configure:4408: cl -c  -TC -nologo  conftest.c 1>&5
conftest.c
configure:4439: checking for highest Windows version supported by this SDK
configure:4494: checking for Windows SDK being recent enough
configure:4529: checking how to run the C preprocessor
configure:4609: checking how to run the C++ preprocessor
configure:4711: checking for a BSD compatible install
configure:4764: checking whether ln -s works
configure:4787: checking for minimum required perl version >= 5.006
configure:4798: checking for full perl installation
configure:4816: checking for doxygen
configure:4865: checking for autoconf
configure:4916: checking for unzip
configure:4972: checking for zip
configure:5026: checking for xargs
configure:5078: checking for rpmbuild
configure:5264: checking compiler version
configure:5282: checking for e:/mozilla-build/mozmake/mozmake.EXE
configure:5282: checking for make
configure:5405: checking for X
configure:5472: cl -E -nologo  conftest.c >/dev/null 2>conftest.out
configure(5468) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'X11/Intrinsic.h': No such file or directory
configure: failed program was:
#line 5467 "configure"
#include "confdefs.h"
#include <X11/Intrinsic.h>
configure:5548: cl -o conftest  -TC -nologo   conftest.c -lXt  1>&5
cl : Command line warning D9035 : option 'o' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-lXt'
conftest.c
conftest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _XtMalloc referenced in function _main
conftest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
configure: failed program was:
#line 5541 "configure"
#include "confdefs.h"

int main() {
XtMalloc()
; return 0; }
configure:6620: cl -c   conftest.c 1>&5
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

conftest.c
configure(6616) : error C2065: '__thumb2__' : undeclared identifier
configure: failed program was:
#line 6613 "configure"
#include "confdefs.h"

int main() {
return sizeof(__thumb2__);
; return 0; }
configure:6874: checking that static assertion macros used in autoconf tests work
configure:6895: cl -c  -TC -nologo  conftest.c 1>&5
conftest.c
configure:6912: cl -c  -TC -nologo  conftest.c 1>&5
conftest.c
configure(6912) : error C2118: negative subscript
configure: failed program was:
#line 6905 "configure"
#include "confdefs.h"

#define CONFIGURE_STATIC_ASSERT(condition) CONFIGURE_STATIC_ASSERT_IMPL(condition, __LINE__)
#define CONFIGURE_STATIC_ASSERT_IMPL(condition, line) CONFIGURE_STATIC_ASSERT_IMPL2(condition, line)
#define CONFIGURE_STATIC_ASSERT_IMPL2(condition, line) typedef int static_assert_line_##line[(condition) ? 1 : -1]

int main() {
CONFIGURE_STATIC_ASSERT(0)
; return 0; }
configure:6935: cl -c  -TP -nologo  conftest.C 1>&5
conftest.C
configure:6952: cl -c  -TP -nologo  conftest.C 1>&5
conftest.C
configure(6952) : error C2118: negative subscript
configure: failed program was:
#line 6945 "configure"
#include "confdefs.h"

#define CONFIGURE_STATIC_ASSERT(condition) CONFIGURE_STATIC_ASSERT_IMPL(condition, __LINE__)
#define CONFIGURE_STATIC_ASSERT_IMPL(condition, line) CONFIGURE_STATIC_ASSERT_IMPL2(condition, line)
#define CONFIGURE_STATIC_ASSERT_IMPL2(condition, line) typedef int static_assert_line_##line[(condition) ? 1 : -1]

int main() {
CONFIGURE_STATIC_ASSERT(0)
; return 0; }
configure:8089: checking for 64-bit OS
configure:8098: cl -c  -TC -nologo  conftest.c 1>&5
conftest.c
configure(8098) : error C2118: negative subscript
configure: failed program was:
#line 8091 "configure"
#include "confdefs.h"

#define CONFIGURE_STATIC_ASSERT(condition) CONFIGURE_STATIC_ASSERT_IMPL(condition, __LINE__)
#define CONFIGURE_STATIC_ASSERT_IMPL(condition, line) CONFIGURE_STATIC_ASSERT_IMPL2(condition, line)
#define CONFIGURE_STATIC_ASSERT_IMPL2(condition, line) typedef int static_assert_line_##line[(condition) ? 1 : -1]

int main() {
CONFIGURE_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(void*) == 8)
; return 0; }
configure:8466: checking for custom <inttypes.h> implementation
configure:9858: checking whether the C++ compiler (cl  -TP -nologo -W3 -Gy -Fd$(COMPILE_PDBFILE) -wd4251 -wd4244 -wd4345 -wd4351 -wd4482 -wd4800 -wd4819 -we4553 -GR-  -LARGEADDRESSAWARE -NXCOMPAT -RELEASE -DYNAMICBASE -SAFESEH) actually is a C++ compiler
configure:9877: cl -o conftest  -TP -nologo -W3 -Gy -Fd$(COMPILE_PDBFILE) -wd4251 -wd4244 -wd4345 -wd4351 -wd4482 -wd4800 -wd4819 -we4553 -GR-   -LARGEADDRESSAWARE -NXCOMPAT -RELEASE -DYNAMICBASE -SAFESEH conftest.C  1>&5
cl : Command line warning D9035 : option 'o' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-LARGEADDRESSAWARE'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-NXCOMPAT'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-RELEASE'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-SAFESEH'
conftest.C
configure:15075: checking for YASM assembler
configure:15081: checking for yasm
configure:16182: checking for application to build
configure:16238: checking if app-specific confvars.sh exists
configure:19699: cl -c  -TC -nologo -W3 -Gy -Fd$(COMPILE_PDBFILE) -wd4244 -wd4819 -we4553  conftest.c 1>&5
conftest.c
configure(19693) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'linux/ethtool.h': No such file or directory
configure: failed program was:
#line 19692 "configure"
#include "confdefs.h"
#include <linux/ethtool.h>
int main() {
 struct ethtool_cmd cmd; cmd.speed_hi = 0; 
; return 0; }
configure:19891: checking __attribute__ ((aligned ())) support
configure:19908: cl -c  -TC -nologo -W3 -Gy -Fd$(COMPILE_PDBFILE) -wd4244 -wd4819 -we4553 -Werror  conftest.c 1>&5
cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Werror'
configure: failed program was:
#line 19901 "configure"
#include "confdefs.h"

int main() {
static char c __attribute__ ((aligned(64))) = 0; return c;
; return 0; }
configure:19908: cl -c  -TC -nologo -W3 -Gy -Fd$(COMPILE_PDBFILE) -wd4244 -wd4819 -we4553 -Werror  conftest.c 1>&5
cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Werror'
configure: failed program was:
#line 19901 "configure"
#include "confdefs.h"

int main() {
static char c __attribute__ ((aligned(32))) = 0; return c;
; return 0; }
configure:19908: cl -c  -TC -nologo -W3 -Gy -Fd$(COMPILE_PDBFILE) -wd4244 -wd4819 -we4553 -Werror  conftest.c 1>&5
cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Werror'
configure: failed program was:
#line 19901 "configure"
#include "confdefs.h"

int main() {
static char c __attribute__ ((aligned(16))) = 0; return c;
; return 0; }
configure:19908: cl -c  -TC -nologo -W3 -Gy -Fd$(COMPILE_PDBFILE) -wd4244 -wd4819 -we4553 -Werror  conftest.c 1>&5
cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Werror'
configure: failed program was:
#line 19901 "configure"
#include "confdefs.h"

int main() {
static char c __attribute__ ((aligned(8))) = 0; return c;
; return 0; }
configure:21069: checking for java
configure:21118: checking for javac
configure:21167: checking for javah
configure:21216: checking for jar
configure:21265: checking for jarsigner
configure:21314: checking for keytool
configure:22014: checking for makensisu-2.46
configure:22072: checking for Unicode NSIS with major version == 2 and minor version >= 46
configure:22120: checking for tar archiver
configure:22126: checking for gnutar
configure:22126: checking for gtar
configure:22126: checking for tar
configure:22163: checking for wget
configure:22169: checking for wget
configure:23038: checking for valid optimization flags
configure:23049: cl -c  -TC -nologo -W3 -Gy -Fd$(COMPILE_PDBFILE) -wd4244 -wd4819 -we4553 -O1  conftest.c 1>&5
conftest.c
configure:25152: checking what kind of list files are supported by the linker
configure:25157: cl -o conftest.obj -c  -TC -nologo -W3 -Gy -Fd$(COMPILE_PDBFILE) -wd4244 -wd4819 -we4553  conftest.c 1>&5
cl : Command line warning D9035 : option 'o' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release
conftest.c
configure:25159: cl -o conftest  -LARGEADDRESSAWARE -NXCOMPAT -RELEASE -DYNAMICBASE -SAFESEH conftest.list  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winmm.lib wsock32.lib advapi32.lib secur32.lib netapi32.lib 1>&5
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

cl : Command line warning D9035 : option 'o' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-LARGEADDRESSAWARE'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-NXCOMPAT'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-RELEASE'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-SAFESEH'
cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'conftest.list', object file assumed
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 10.00.40219.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:conftest.exe 
/out:conftest.exe 
conftest.list 
kernel32.lib 
user32.lib 
gdi32.lib 
winmm.lib 
wsock32.lib 
advapi32.lib 
secur32.lib 
netapi32.lib 
conftest.list : fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x14
configure:25163: cl -o conftest  -LARGEADDRESSAWARE -NXCOMPAT -RELEASE -DYNAMICBASE -SAFESEH -Wl,-filelist,conftest.list  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winmm.lib wsock32.lib advapi32.lib secur32.lib netapi32.lib 1>&5
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

cl : Command line warning D9035 : option 'o' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release
cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wl,-filelist,conftest.list'
configure:25165: cl -o conftest  -LARGEADDRESSAWARE -NXCOMPAT -RELEASE -DYNAMICBASE -SAFESEH @conftest.list  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winmm.lib wsock32.lib advapi32.lib secur32.lib netapi32.lib 1>&5
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

cl : Command line warning D9035 : option 'o' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release
cl conftest.obj

cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-LARGEADDRESSAWARE'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-NXCOMPAT'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-RELEASE'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-SAFESEH'
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 10.00.40219.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:conftest.exe 
/out:conftest.exe 
conftest.obj 
kernel32.lib 
user32.lib 
gdi32.lib 
winmm.lib 
wsock32.lib 
advapi32.lib 
secur32.lib 
netapi32.lib 
configure:25971: checking for stdint.h
configure:25984: cl -c  -TC -nologo -W3 -Gy -Fd$(COMPILE_PDBFILE) -wd4244 -wd4819 -we4553  conftest.c 1>&5
conftest.c
configure:25971: checking for inttypes.h
configure:25984: cl -c  -TC -nologo -W3 -Gy -Fd$(COMPILE_PDBFILE) -wd4244 -wd4819 -we4553  conftest.c 1>&5
conftest.c
configure(25978) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'inttypes.h': No such file or directory
configure: failed program was:
#line 25976 "configure"
#include "confdefs.h"

#include <inttypes.h>
int main() {

; return 0; }
configure:25971: checking for sys/int_types.h
configure:25984: cl -c  -TC -nologo -W3 -Gy -Fd$(COMPILE_PDBFILE) -wd4244 -wd4819 -we4553  conftest.c 1>&5
conftest.c
configure(25978) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sys/int_types.h': No such file or directory
configure: failed program was:
#line 25976 "configure"
#include "confdefs.h"

#include <sys/int_types.h>
int main() {

; return 0; }
configure:26071: checking for d3d9.h
configure:26084: cl -c  -TC -nologo -W3 -Gy -Fd$(COMPILE_PDBFILE) -wd4244 -wd4819 -we4553  conftest.c 1>&5
conftest.c
configure:26108: checking for d3d10.h
configure:26121: cl -c  -TC -nologo -W3 -Gy -Fd$(COMPILE_PDBFILE) -wd4244 -wd4819 -we4553  conftest.c 1>&5
conftest.c
configure:27327: checking for posix_fallocate
configure:27337: cl -o conftest -TC -nologo -W3 -Gy -Fd$(COMPILE_PDBFILE) -wd4244 -wd4819 -we4553   -LARGEADDRESSAWARE -NXCOMPAT -RELEASE -DYNAMICBASE -SAFESEH conftest.c  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winmm.lib wsock32.lib advapi32.lib secur32.lib netapi32.lib 1>&5
cl : Command line warning D9035 : option 'o' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-LARGEADDRESSAWARE'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-NXCOMPAT'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-RELEASE'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-SAFESEH'
conftest.c
configure(27333) : warning C4013: 'posix_fallocate' undefined; assuming extern returning int
kernel32.lib
c1 : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'kernel32.lib': No such file or directory
user32.lib
c1 : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'user32.lib': No such file or directory
gdi32.lib
c1 : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'gdi32.lib': No such file or directory
winmm.lib
c1 : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'winmm.lib': No such file or directory
wsock32.lib
c1 : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wsock32.lib': No such file or directory
advapi32.lib
c1 : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'advapi32.lib': No such file or directory
secur32.lib
c1 : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'secur32.lib': No such file or directory
netapi32.lib
c1 : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'netapi32.lib': No such file or directory
Generating Code...
configure: failed program was:
#line 27329 "configure"
#include "confdefs.h"
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600
  #include <fcntl.h>
int main() {
posix_fallocate(0, 0, 0);
; return 0; }
configure: error: e:/securebrowser7_release/env/mozilla/js/src/configure failed for js/src
```

It would be really helpful if someone could help me overcome this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending long hours, I was able to get this working on a VirtualBox environment with Windows 7 installed.

I did not investigate as to why it didn't work on Windows 8.1 earlier. This could have been a problem with the c++ compilers I suppose if I had to take the wildest guess.